# Serial to RJ45 connection to Brocade FWS 648S 48port Switch

Tags: switch, management

this is going to sound really dumb, but I've forgotten how to connect and manage a switch if the console interface is serial and the other end is an RJ45. The switch I'm working on is a Brocade FWS 648G 48 port switch and it has a serial port as it's console interface and the RJ45 goes in my laptop - obviously this doesnt create a COM port  ( Do i need some kind of converter to USB? ) Anyway, usually on older laptops I remember using hyper terminal but they took this away on windows 10. Just a question really on how any of you manage a switch like this ( im used to cisco where the console port is the rj45 jack and the serial end has a serial to usb adapter on and use putty). Again apologies for the dumb question, thanks in advance.

Here is an image to show what I mean - https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3mEC.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the DB9 serial end goes to a switch and then another serial connector to your laptop. If your laptop doesn't have a serial connector, you need to use something like a USB-Serial adapter where it will have a male DB9 connection that will link with the cable connected to your switch.

[image]

Sometimes newer models will allow you to use a RJ45 connectors to the switch with a serial connection going to your laptop which seems what you have, so you might be using the wrong cable if your Brocade switch does not have a console port that is RJ45.

Just be careful because each vendor seem to do their own cables and even though they look the same, the pinouts might be completely different. For example, I have an extreme networks cable and a HP cable that do not work together, but a cable to the Cisco switches seems to work.

In regards to Hyper-Terminal, this can still be found floating around the Internet. But most people will use free clients such as Putty or Tera Term which can do serial, telnet, ssh, etc.

Hope this helps you on your quest.

SleepyMan

Comment: Thanks for your help sleepyman - im hoping this image might explain my situation better  - http://imgur.com/Ten8UM6

Comment: I already have one of those adaptors but as you can see the switch uses the console port itself so the situation is flipped.

Comment: I think the cable isn't the correct one for that switch model. That cable seems to be for a switch model that uses the RJ45 as the console port and not a DB9. From the looks what you need is a serial connection on both ends and then use a adapter if you haven't got a serial connection on your laptop.

Comment: ah, thanks for the confirmation, thought i was going crazy! will look for the correct cable :)

Comment: This might be of helps as well: http://community.brocade.com/t5/Design-Build/How-To-Connect-a-Console-Cable-to-Brocade-Hardware/ta-p/37039

Comment: Well i found the correct cable and now can console to the switch - I must have had a blonde moment there as it all makes sense now. Thanks again for your assistance!